# How to add a JPanel from a diffent class to another JPanel on mouse click

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I've been trying to populate a JPanel (here reffered to as 'BulletinsJPanel') in a class reffered to as 'Home.java' with a textfield (here reffered to as 'readerSetTxtJTextField') when a JLabel is clicked. ReaderPanel is in another class called 'Reader.java' which is supposed to read the contents of a text file and populate a JTextField object with a line of text.

I'm using netbeans which doesn't show me any code error highlights.

I would really appreciate some help in getting the textfield 'readerSetTxtJTextField' to show. Thanks a lot in advance.

Heres my code:

```
// The class Home

package Panels;
public class Home extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    // Here's a method in the class 'Home.java' which should populate 'BulletinsJPanel' with the contents
    private void MouseClickedList(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        BulletinsJPanel.add(Reader.readerMouseClickedList());
        BulletinsJPanel.revalidate();
        BulletinsJPanel.repaint();
    }
}

// Now the class Reader below

package Database;
public class Reader {
    public static JTextField readerSetTxtJTextField;

    public static JTextField readerMouseClickedList() {                                  
        try {
            // Our code
            String fileURL = "/D:/TestFile.txt/";
            List<String[]> matches = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            String finalText;

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileURL);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInputStream));

            String stringLine;

            while((stringLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String splittable = "[\\s]", splitLenth = "{955}";
                if(stringLine.startsWith("2013001")) {
                    String[] splits = stringLine.split(splittable + splitLenth );

                    matches.add(splits);
                }
            }
            dataInputStream.close();

            for(String[] items : matches) {
                int itemsLength = items.length;
                int i;
                for(i = 0; i <= itemsLength; i++) {
                    finalText = (items[i]);

                    readerSetTxtJTextField = new JTextField();
                    readerSetTxtJTextField.setText(finalText);
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return readerSetTxtJTextField;
    }                                 

}
```

Comment: Please print your full error message and indicate which line throws the exception. Also change `System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());` to just `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: And it sounds like a JList would work better for your needs here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. All I get is "Error: 1" when the JLabel is clicked. The program runs well until the JLabel is clicked.

Comment: Again, change your catch block, and then come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick fix to your error , Change :

```
for(i = 0; i <= itemsLength; i++)
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mac. That was a lot  helpful. It got rid of the error message. However, I still cannot get the textfield 'readerSetTxtJTextField' to show.

Comment: Just put the following Line in your `MouseClickedList` method `System.out.println(Reader.readerMouseClickedList().getText());` and tell me its output.

Comment: Thanks again. It outputs the text I want displayed. How do I get that text to show in the textfield 'readerSetTxtJTextField' in the JPanel 'BulletinsJPanel'. I just stated teaching myself how to program, if this seems too simple to do.

Comment: I get this text when I click the JLabel: "2013001 Jaymarion Manalo L. Service Crew March 15, 2013   8:00   12:00   13:00   17:00   10.0"

Comment: `BulletinsJPanel` Is it an object of `JPanel`? If yes then , is it added to the underlying container..and what `layout` have you specified for it?

Comment: BulletinsJPanel is already in the JFrame which is already running. The textfield is supposed to be added to the BulletinsJPanel when the JLabel is clicked, kind of like an update to BulletinsJPanel which was innitially empty. I'm using netbeans which shows that the BulletinsJPanel's layout is 'Free Design'

Comment: Can you set the layout of `BulletinsJPanel` as `FlowLayout`?